# Use Manipulate for a global variable

Tags: manipulate, dynamic, variable

I do have a global variable called w1, which is used as a factor in a dataset, however I want to make this factor dynamic.

```
w1 = 0.2;

w2 = 0.2;

w3 = 0.2;

w4 = 0.2;

w5 = 0.2;

column1 = w1*RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 100];

column2 = w2*RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 100];

column3 = w3*RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 100];

column4 = w4*RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 100];

column5 = w5*RandomInteger[{1, 5}, 100];

column6 = RandomInteger[{0, 1}, 100];
```

(*Creating a matrix consisting of those 6 columns, named dummydata*)

```
dummydata = {column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6};
```

So the variable I am talking about would be, f.e. w1. Any help would be much appreciated! 
The goal would be to create a dataset that displays those values dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
w2 = 0.2;
w3 = 0.2;
w4 = 0.2;
w5 = 0.2;
n = 10;
A = N[Join[RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {n, 5}], RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {n, 1}], 2]];
Block[{w},
  dummydata = w \[Function] Evaluate[A.DiagonalMatrix[{w, w2, w3, w4, w5, 1.}]]
];
Manipulate[
 MatrixForm[dummydata[w]],
 {w, 0, 1}
 ]
```